# SSIS Data integration between SQL Server database to IBM AS400

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ibm-midrange, ssis-2008

Is there a way to insert data into an AS/400 library table from a SQL Server database with SSIS 2008r2? We did a test and we can see the tables in the library, but it gives an error when you click on "mappings", see image.

[image: Error SSIS]

If we put Journalling on in the AS/400 system the columns are showing and I can make mappings. But this option is creating a lot of extra (logging) space on the AS/400 system, that we don't have or want.

Is there a way to get this work without using the Journaling option?

Comment: Journaling is necessary for commitment control. Maybe it would work if you could turn off commitment control in SQL Server?

Comment: Sometimes when error messages suggest that commitment control is a stumbling block, it can be remedied by setting up the connection to be auto-committing.

Comment: How do you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to change the "data access mode" to a "SQL command".

Fill in by the SQL command text the following:

```
SELECT COLUMN_A AS COLUMN_A, 
       COLUMN_B AS COLUMN_B
FROM TABLE
```

And now you can access the mappings of the table in the AS/400 system/library